# How to expose the node creation form in the front page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I created a new content type "project" and I want to create a **view** where every one can add a node (create a content) with my content type.

How to expose the form (to add a new project node) in the front (I do not just want to expose a link to add such node)?

In `admin/people/permissions` I granted the permission for *ANONYMOUS USER* to be able to create a new content.

Comment: Do you want to show *Add Project* link only so any user can add a project, right?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I want to give anonymous user permissions to mydrupal/node/add/project (this is my view).. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display content type form you can use [formblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module as it description explains:

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

- Enable the module
- Go to **Project** `admin/structure/types/manage/project`
- On the bottom left vertical tabs there'd be a *Form Block*, check **Enable data entry from a block** and save
- Go to `admin/structure/block` and enable **Project form block**

[image]

I hope this'd help you.

Comment: Thanks Sir, that expose a link but I want to expose the form

Comment: @A.Sana see the updated answer